# Double-Jointed Leg Rig doesn't equally distribute rotation amongst joints

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, inverse-kinematics

I'm trying to make a simple leg rig, but I want to make the knee have its own bone. The rotation should interpolate between the other two bones. I have Inverse Kinematics set up, but it doesn't rotate the joints equally when I move it around. Are there any good methods to do this? Of course, this could possibly work with Forward Kinematics, but that is not how I want to go about it.

I'm not worried about mesh deformations since my model is made up of multiple objects.[image]

As you can see in this image, it's a little off. Its shape should look like an isosceles trapezoid, but this one isn't symmetrical. It seems to rotate the shin more than it does the knee. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the thigh and shin bones are the same length, there is a simple solution.

**Step 1**

[image]

Create an offsetted IK system as shown in Figure 1. In the figure the *Knee.L.001* bone has a Damped Track constraint to the *ShinIK.L* one. And the *Thigh.L.001*, *Shin.L.001*, *ShunIK.L* and *KneeIK.L* bones make up the basic IK system.

***Step 2***

[image]

Add deforming bones, *Thigh.L*  and *Knee.L*, as shown in Figure 2. However the *Thigh.L.001* and *Knee.L.001* bones are intentionally hidden. In the figure the *Thigh.L* bone's rotation is constrainted by the *Thigh.L.001*. And the *Knee.L* bone has a Damped Track constraint to the *Shin.L* one.